# KnexJS: How do you insert/update a timestamp field with current timestamp?

Tags: timestamp, insert-update, knex.js

Title basically says it all.

I am predominantly interested in the update case. Suppose we are trying update a record that has a timestamp field, and we wish to set that field to the timestamp of when the record is updated. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some experimentation, I've figured out the proper solution. You can use multiple `.update(...)` calls on the same query without screwing anything up, so long as you don't use multiple objects (this includes `knex.raw`). You can combine one object style call with field/value style calls, such as:

```
knex('table').update({ x: 1, y: 2 }).update('modified_at', knex.fn.now()).where(...) // and so on.
```